# Finding font type using tess4j

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am new to OCR. I am using java wrapper **Tess4J** API to get the text from image and I am able to get the text. Using same tess4j API I want to get the font properties.

1. How can I get the font style (Bold, Italic, Underline) of the retrieved text.
2. How can I get the font type (Times, Lucida Console, Arial) of the retrieved text.
3. How can I get the font size.

Any thoughts.

Comment: You don't. Tesseract does not support it

Answer (score 2):

I found that using TessAPI1.TessResultIterator we can find the font properties. I found some code samples here http://sourceforge.net/p/tess4j/code/181/tree/Tess4J_3/trunk/test/net/sourceforge/tess4j/TessAPI1Test.java.

I tested this for font Verana and Times New Roman

Comment: The method testResultIterator() contains the code that might be useful for the mentioned font properties. Also found TessAPI1.TessResultIteratorSymbolIsSubscript(ri) and TessAPI1.TessResultIteratorSymbolIsSuperscript(ri) kind of useful.